# move_uploaded_file not moving file with no error - searched other questions

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched all the questions of a similar nature yet have not been able to find the solution.  I have checked my php.ini file and all permission and sizes are appropriate.  The file is being created in mysql but I can not get a copy moved to my local folder.  I have tried copy as well as setting permission with the commented out code seen below.  Again, no errors are thrown that I can find.

Thank you.  If you see the answer in another post feel free to supply a link.

```
<?php require_once("include/DB.php");?>
<?php require_once("include/Sessions.php");?>
<?php require_once("include/Functions.php");?>
<?php 

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


    $target_file = ($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);
    $Target =__DIR__."\Uploads\\".basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);

$Query="INSERT INTO admin_panel (image)
VALUES('$target_file')";

$Execute=mysqli_query($Connection, $Query);
chmod($target_dir,0755);
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image'],['tmp_name'], $Target)){
    $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]="uploaded ". $Target;
    Redirect_to("testImage2.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="not uploaded ". $Target;
    Redirect_to("testImage2.php");

} 

if($Execute){
    $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]="Post Added Successfully";
    Redirect_to("testImage2.php");
}else{
$_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Something went wrong failed to add";
Redirect_to("testImage2.php");

}
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo Message(); 


        echo SuccessMessage();
        ?>
<form action="testImage2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="Image" id="Image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `($_FILES['Image'],['tmp_name']` you should be getting an error from the comma in there.

Comment: For whatever reason an error wasn't being thrown, unless it's in a log I haven't checked.  However, hours of debugging over a comma, sonofa...

Comment: I take it that that solved the question then?

Comment: Reason why you probably didn't get an error is that the comma could very well be a valid character in PHP. I've seen other cases similar to this before.